# Would it hurt my credit score/report if a company decided to close my account for security reasons?

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

Recently I received a letter from my credit card company asking me to send them a proof of identity/address as they have frozen my account and doing security checks.
I can't be bothered to send them the documents they are asking for and the letter I received stated that they will close my account if I don't provide the required documents.
I have no problem with them closing the account and I'll pay the entire amount I owe them in one go if they demand that.
However the question is: would it look bad on my credit report?

Comment: I'm curious. How long has the credit card been open, what portion of the credit line have you used, and had you made any payments before they requested the additional information?

Comment: Sounds like you're being scammed.

Comment: If your account is labelled as closed due to suspected fraud, then your credit rating may become irrelevant.  There are lots of people who lend to someone with a poor credit history, but nobody will lend to a fraudster.

Answer (score 3):

Be very careful here.  You should definitely phone the card company and confirm that they are the ones who sent you this letter.  This could be a scam.

Update:  Per the comments, always use a phone number or address that you have gotten from a verified source (back of your credit card or credit card statement) or from a trusted third party (directory information, ssl secured website, etc.)  Though some phishing schemes can use decent fakes for websites, so be cautious when using the internet to research such things.

Having an account closed out due to security reasons will show on your credit report.  Loan officers will see this.  It creates a question in their mind, and they will likely ask you questions about it if you apply for credit in the future.

My advice is to contact your card company, confirm they sent the letter, and discuss what you can send them short of going through the process of renewing your passport.  Some other combination of documentation.  As long as you stay non-confrontational, they should work with you.  Then, once you clear up the security question, you should evaluate whether you want to continue being their customer.  On one hand, they're looking out for your interest, and you'll likely learn how to prevent this situation in the future.  On the other, you are having to go through a bit of trouble.  Balance that out and cleanly close the account if you feel you need to do so.

Comment: Please add that in such circumstances, you should phone the company **by looking up their customer service number directly**. Use google, find the main corporate website, and go to the 'contact us' page. Any number provided by the potential fraudster, be it by mail, e-mail, or whatever, could be false, directing you to a non-legitimate answering service.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon or the phone number printed on the card itself (usually easiest) or on a recent statement (you _do_ save your statements right?!). But _not_ the email or SMS etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your post didn't state what country you're in, so the answer to this will depend, but I'll offer some general advice anyway, since I think it is appropriate to the circumstance.

The statement "I can't be bothered" raises questions for me.  After all, if you're worried about how they'll report it, why not just send them the documents they ask for to satisfy them and then just close the account at a later date like normal on your own?

If you don't want to run the risk of how they'll report this then *MAKE* the time to send them the documents they ask for?  It's the easiest and safest course of course.

Comment: Some people are lazy and I am one of them, my passport has expired and I have renew it and this means I have call them and inform them that I'll submit the required documents one I renew my passport. Also they want my bank statements and the source of the money etc.. this will take some good amount of time from me. Nothing is dodgy here but it does not worth it to waste my time over a simple credit card

Comment: @Ulkoma In many cases, an expired passport can be used.  You're not trying to cross a border so this may be one of those cases.